# Should unit tests use absolute values?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I came along a unit test for a method that does mapping between two classes.

```
@Test
public void testMapping() {
    MappingClass mappingClass = new MappingClass();
    FromClass fromClass = new FromClass("string.value");

    ToClass toClass = mappingClass.map(fromClass);

    //This...
    assertEquals(fromClass.getStringValue(), toClass.getMappedStringValue());
    //... or this?
    assertEquals("string.value", toClass.getMappedStringValue());
}
```

The getter coincidentally contains the same string value and I believe the code was written like this because the writer knew the map method would call the getter. Exactly for this reason I would expect the absolute value, since from a TDD perspective, you're supposed to be unaware of the implementation.

What are the benefits for a unit test to evaluate the absolute value of the subject over evaluating a derived value?

**Edit**: To avoid confusion, the implementation would be like this:

```
public class FromClass {
    private String stringValue;

    public FromClass(String stringValue) {

        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }
}

public class ToClass {

    private String mappedStringValue;

    public ToClass(String mappedStringValue) {
        this.mappedStringValue = mappedStringValue;
    }

    public String getMappedStringValue(){
        return mappedStringValue;
    }
}

public class MappingClass {

    public ToClass map(FromClass fromClass){
        return new ToClass(fromClass.getStringValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's OK to make test cases with the awareness of implementation.  This way you can target specific weakness points in that implementation.

Comment: "*The getter coincidentally contains the same string value and I believe the code was written like this because the writer knew the map method would call the getter*" - I'm confused. Which getter? Which value (`string.value`? Or is this some `foo-bar` example)? It would help if we knew the contracts for these methods. I'm struggling to see the leaking implementation details.

Comment: The _contract_ was clear from context, and not really relevant imo

Comment: The contract is *not* clear.. Does `map` document that it'll return a mapped version containing the specified value? If so, then this is to be expected, and I don't see any issues with your assert: you're asserting that the value from `ToClass` matches `FromClass`. Using your second option, you wouldn't really be comparing what you're really trying to compare (the two objects). What if you later wanted `FromClass` to wrap the value, then uses this wrapped version for `ToClass` aswell? Then yeah, users would be forced to learn of the implementation to understand why their test fails.

Comment: This classes are merely a "Data Transfer objects" (DTOs) or  "value container" without any *business related* behavior. But in unittest we verify *business behavior*. Also: this is *too simple to fail*. Therefore you should not test it explicitly with a *unittest* since you will use it in other unittest for your real *business logic* which will show if this classes have problems.

Comment: Of course this is a simple example, its only purpose is to provide context. My question remains the same if this was an integration test. Whether or not this class should be tested is irrelevant.

Comment: Can this question be reopened please? I've edited my description to invite more fact-based replies. Furthermore I would like to provide an answer myself

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would do
`String expected="string.value"`; and use it twice (once in actual, once in expected) I think it shows intention just fine. It shows that reusing value is not incidental but expected.

Also, I think the test would be more readable if written as

> ```
> @Test public void testMapping() {
> MappingClass sut= new MappingClass(); //sut=system under test
> FromClass fromClass = new FromClass("string.value");
>
> ToClass actual= mappingClass.map(fromClass);
> ToClass expected = //construct new object
>
> assertEquals(expected, actual);
> ```

This requires correct `equals` implementation in `ToClass`  Object. In This solution is bullet-prof against changes (new fields in `ToClass`).
To be sure that your `equals` implementation is bullet-proof against changes in `ToClass` you may write yet another test for equals/hashcode. Use https://github.com/jqno/equalsverifier -your equals test will fail if you add new fields to `ToClass`.

Equals/hashcode/toString implementation in value objects (like `FromClass, ToClass`) is good idea- it makes those class more powerful (they could be keys in Map, elements in Set, etc)  and pleasant to use .

Comment: As would I, but what advantage does it have over the alternative?

Comment: I would use variable for "string.value" to show that it is intended reuse. Also see edited post about using whole objects (compared using equals) and fully automated equals test.

Comment: @TomVW the main advantage to would be readability, and that is very important in a unit test!

Comment: @Jocke is right. Readability is very important  for unit test. Otherwise they do not serve their role as documentation and are hard to maintain. They tend out to be commented out/deleted or just ignored when fail, so they stop to serve any useful role.

Comment: The creation of a new expected object is not a good solution. When your test fails, you only get limited information about the equality: they're not equal. No clue which aspects of the equality causes the failure.